# How to Normalise a loss function containing actual values?

Tags: optimization, normalization, loss-functions

I defined a loss function that I am trying to optimise consisting of two elements. let's say a and b:

w1 * (a_actual - a_measured)^2 + w2* (b_actual - b_measured)^2

I am trying to simplify the optimisation process by setting both w1 and w2 to 1. I want two terms to have a same contribution but the an and b have different scales. Dividing by the mean value does not work since that also leads to not equal weights. What is the best way of doing this?

Comment: You have, by definition, a multicriteria optimization problem, and there will unfortunately be no way around understanding the tradeoffs you would accept between errors in a and b. If you want the two terms to have "the same contribution" means that you need to decide what "same" means, i.e., you need to decide how to compare (errors in) a and b. You need to decide how to compare your apples and your oranges.

Answer (score 0):

This is the job of the w1/2. You can't leave them away. The exact definition of your loss function has an impact on the result and its interpretation. If you expect truly meaningful results, you better use a chi-2 or log-likelihood loss function with clearly understood statistics.

The details depend a lot on the data you have at hand and you told nothing about this in your question. For example, if the as and bs are measurements, with an actual measurement uncertainty, Ea and Eb, then you could use:

`w1=1/Ea^2` and `w2=1/Eb^2`

If you nothing about the uncertainties, but your data is "counting" data you can can assume Poisson errors:

`w1=1/a_actual` and `w2=1/b_actual` (and use the `expected` values, if the `actual` ones are zero).

Or, if you know the variance/RMS of your data you may use this, too:

`w1=1/VarA` and `w2=1/VarB`.

Using the mean, as you tried out yourself, makes no sense in terms of statistics.

Consider in all these cases, that the expectation-value of your optimization will definitely change with the choices of w1 and w2. So they absolutely matter. Another result of a reasonable optimization is the `1-sigma` contour, or "error" (or how you want to call it) and here the choice of w1 and w2 matters even more.

If wanted to optimize something I wanted to understand the uncertainty of the outcome. You probably have to think more about this...